# Show asker AND editor

Tags: discussion, feature-request, faq-suggestion

This is a suggestion: when we have the list of questions on screen, we can see below each of them the name of the asker, *unless* it has been editted by someone, situation in which we can read the name of the editor. My suggestion would be to show the asker's AND the editor's names, so that we can see who actually asked.

Isn't this feasible and desirable?